# Are questions about the blender foundation website/other services on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about things like the blender store and blender cloud on topic?

E.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28333/599

It doesn't seem to fit in our [scope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> The Blender Stack Exchange site is for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

Comment: Pretty sure  these are off topic.. But just to be sure

Comment: When I wrote my answer I did not even notice that I quoted the same thing that you did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that they are definitely off topic.
This site is about the software [blender](http://blender.org). Not blender's site or services (even the official site).

> Blender Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

We should not start to accept this type of question. Website support should always be directed to the site's contact or support.

As an example, a question about not being able to watch a CGcookie or Guru tutorial, would not even be considered as on topic.

I voted to close the linked question.

Comment: We accept `documentation` questions to an extent but regarding the site, that's a no.